# Rewrite rule for mobile URL

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have to redirect mobile users to a new URL (`/amp/...`) so I added this snippet code to my Apache site config:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://test.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/amp/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /amp/$1 [L,R=302]`
```

The problem is that I'm only redirected when requesting the home page (`test.domain.com`), and not when I request to any other URL (e.g. `test.domain.com/category/web`). Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

This is a Wordpress site, and the full rewrite module is:

```
<Directory /var/www/project>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options None FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^uploads/(.+) http://myCDN.com/uploads/$1  [R,L]
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://test.domain.com [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/amp/.*$
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /amp/$1 [L,R=302]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: _Aside:_ "`Options None FollowSymLinks`" - That doesn't really make sense, it should simply be `Options FollowSymLinks`.

Answer (score 1):

Your redirect needs to go *before* the front controller (internal rewrite). The *front controller* is catching every request, except for the document root (home page). So your redirect is only being processed for the home page and is simply being ignored for all other requests.

In other words:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://test.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/amp/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /amp/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^uploads/(.+) http://myCDN.com/uploads/$1  [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

As a general rule, external redirects should always go before internal rewrites.

You mention this is in your "Apache site config". I assume these directives are in a `<Directory>` container *within* your "site config" (ie. in a *directory context*). (These directives would simply not work in a *server config* or *virtual host* context, ie. directly in your "site config".)

Comment: I'm redirected to `domain.com/amp/index.php` when I request any url

Comment: Ah, your front controller will still try to route the redirected URL. You'll need an _exception_ to prevent this. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Umm, I'm not uing `.htaccess` and don't want to. I'm adding all rules in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.conf`.

Comment: Yes, that's OK. But presumably these directives are inside a `<Directory>` container? It's just that a pattern such as `^uploads/(.+)` would never match in a virtual host (or server config) context. Did you try the exception I added (update#2)?

Comment: Yes, inside a `<Directory>`. I tried, but this condition is checked at `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/amp/.*$`. Anyway, I have had to add it bellow the other rules in order to work, and I'm facing the same problem described in the question.

Comment: Yes, there is a "similar" condition in your redirect, but the `RewriteRule ^amp/ - [L]` is a separate rule that needs to be added before the existing directives (or specifically before the front controller) to prevent the redirect to `domain.com/amp/index.php`. (Adding it at the end won't do anything.) Alternatively, you can add the same `RewriteCond` directive that you just mentioned, to your _front controller_.

Comment: If I add the `RewriteRule ^amp/ - [L]` rule at below the `RewiteBase`, I have the same problem, and also I'm redirected to "Not found" for the home page although the url exists: `domain.com/amp/`

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, scrub that... just noticed your `/amp` directory in the redirected URL. Do you have any other directives that relate to the `/amp` subdirectory? Including `<Directory>` containers or `.htaccess` files? Also, check the network traffic in the browser... what redirects do you see? Just a single redirect from `test.domain.com/category/web` to `test.domain.com/amp/index.php`, or multiple redirects?

Comment: No redirect for `test.domain.com/category/web`. Just one for `test.domain.com` to `test.domain.com/amp/`

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: But in your first comment, you stated: "I'm redirected to `domain.com/amp/index.php` when I request any url"? - That is presumably after you moved the redirect to the top (which is still required)?

Comment: I see. I've added the snippet to the top and the `RewriteRule ^amp/ - [L]` above it. Then, I'm redirected also for not home page to `/amp/...`, but in both I get a "Not Found" exception.

Comment: "scrub that" - You should probably remove the `RewriteRule ^amp/ - [L]` directive (I missed the `/amp` directory in `domain.com/amp/index.php` when I suggested that). Can you just confirm that you are then still being redirected to `/amp/index.php`?

Comment: Yes, I confirm it. With multiple redirections.

Comment: And what precisely are the "multiple" redirections. (This code should only ever result in _one_ redirection, so maybe there is _something else_ going on?)

Comment: Many 302 redirections from `/amp/index.php` to the same URL.